# Implement Future trait based on future available inside the struct

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, rust-futures, rust-async-std

I'm trying to create a `DelayedValue` future that resolves to a value after a certain time period has elapsed. To do this I simply wanted to wrap the [`Sleep`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/struct.Sleep.html) future from `tokio` crate. But I get errors relating to `Pin` and no matter what I do I can't seem to call the `poll` method on the underlying `Sleep` member.

For reference here is a full program which fails to compile but should illustrate what I want:

```
use futures::task::{Context, Poll};
use futures::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Sleep, Duration};

struct DelayedValue<T> {
    value: T,
    sleep: Sleep,
}

impl<T> Future for DelayedValue<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match &mut self.sleep.poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(()) => Poll::Ready(self.value),
            x => x,
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let dv = DelayedValue {
        value: 10_u8,
        sleep: sleep(Duration::from_millis(5000)),
    };

    println!("waiting for delayed value");
    
    let v = dv.await;
    println!("delayed value: {}", v);
}
```

There is also a playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d573d8dcbbef5c99314d98cacc3d6c92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`pin-project`](https://docs.rs/pin-project) or [`pin-project-lite`](https://docs.rs/pin-project-lite):

```rust
pin_project_lite::pin_project! {
    struct DelayedValue<T> {
        value: Option<T>,
        #[pin]
        sleep: Sleep,
    }
}

impl<T> Future for DelayedValue<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.project();
        match this.sleep.poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(()) => Poll::Ready(this.value.take().unwrap()),
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This certainly works. But I would be very interested what's going on here. If you can could you please explain a bit more? Or link to docs or blog post that covers this?

Comment: @JohnSmith I linked to the docs of the crates. These crates allow you to project a `Pin<&mut Struct>` into `Pin<&mut Field>`s or `&mut Field`s, depending on whether you choose the field to be `#[pin]` or not.

Comment: What I was looking for is this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/pin/index.html#projections-and-structural-pinning

Answer (score 0):

For reference, since I only needed this for this struct I opted to not use `pin-project`. Instead I implemented it myself for the field I needed:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DelayedValue<T: Copy> {
    value: T,
    sleep: Sleep,
}

impl<T: Copy> DelayedValue<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T, sleep: Sleep) -> DelayedValue<T> {
        DelayedValue {value, sleep}
    }
}

impl<T: Copy> Future for DelayedValue<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let x = self.value;
        let s = unsafe { self.map_unchecked_mut(|s| &mut s.sleep) };

        match &mut s.poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(()) => Poll::Ready(x),
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to just `map` the result of a `Sleep` future instead of implementing a full new struct:

```
use futures::FutureExt;
use tokio::time::{ Duration, sleep };

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let dv = sleep (Duration::from_millis (5000)).map (|_| { 10_u8 });

    println!("waiting for delayed value");
    
    let v = dv.await;
    println!("delayed value: {}", v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7df6d1583f85284a02c2e8804175e9b)